# Not able to get files under directory in web application(java)

Tags: java

step1

I am using the following code to get files under scripts directory

```
File directory = new File("scripts");
File[] dirlist = directory.listFiles();
```

It is working fine in stand alone application but when i build this application as jar and place it lib folder of another web application it is giving null pointer exception. It was trying to pickup the folder from eclipse source folder location(`C:\softwares\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32\eclipse\scripts`). I am trying to solve this from couple of days but no luck. If any help appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should use absolute paths (and base them on some property in a property file).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate your answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse won't be there when you deploy to the production server. You'll have to move or copy the scripts into the webapp, as resources. Then, use `ServletContext.getRealPath()` to get the real path to `"scripts"`, convert that to a `File,` and then proceed as per your second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
ServletContext application = getServletContext();
String fullPath = application.getRealPath("");
 fullPath = fullPath + "/scripts/";
File directory = new File(fullPath);
```